# Creating Coinbase acct for a friend

Tags: bitcoin-core, fraud, account-control

A friend of my recently asked me to create a Coinbase account for her. She noted she had an acct already, but has issues getting into it for "lack of activity". Anyway, I have received no explanation as to why she can't open a new acct for herself. I am very concerned about creating an acct for her in that my personal information is on this acct, yet she will be using it. Am I overly concerned about nothing? Is there anything that could come back and bite me with my link to her activity?

Terry

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your friend is an online friend that you haven't met in real life, haven't taken photos of, haven't visited their home and haven't met and chatted with their parents and common friends in real life.

An account like that can be used to launder the proceeds of criminal activity. Since your personal information is attached to the account it is you who may have to sit in an interview room and persuade skeptical law enforcement officials that your friend is not a fiction you created and that you haven't profited from the proceeds of crime, potentially seriously nasty crime, that went through what appears to be your account.

Anyone who asks you to create a financial account for them isn't your friend or is so hopelessly unaware of basic security that they need to be talked out of it and shown a better way to achieve their objectives.

---

Apart from all that, you will be deliberately breaching Coinbase terms and conditions of use. By knowingly doing so you are culpable in assisting crime.

Section 1.2 of https://www.coinbase.com/legal/user_agreement/united_states says :

> By registering or using a Coinbase Account you agree and represent that you have created your Coinbase Account and you will use your Coinbase Account only for yourself, and not on behalf of any third party

section 6.6 says

> You are responsible for creating a strong password and maintaining security and control of any and all electronic devices, IDs, passwords, hints, personal identification numbers (PINs), API keys or any other codes that you use to access the Coinbase Services. Any loss or compromise of the foregoing information and/or your personal information may result in unauthorized access to your Coinbase Account(s) by third-parties and the loss or theft of any Digital Assets and/or funds held in your Coinbase Account(s) and any associated accounts, including your linked bank account(s) and credit card(s).

see also 8.1 about your indemnification of Coinbase if you breach any term (such as 1.2). Your actions are never going to be consequence free.